# It's seems hibernate ignores allocationSize

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying different hibernate id generation strategies and I've noticed that it seems like hibernate ignores `allocationSize`.

I have the following entity class:

```
@Entity
@TableGenerator(name = "id_gen", allocationSize = 100)
public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "id_gen")
    private long id;
    private String title;
}
```

When I run the following code:

```
em.persist(book); //id is 0
em.persist(book1); // id is 0
```

This is what gets logged:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        tbl.next_val 
    from
        id_gen tbl 
    where
        tbl.sequence_name=? for update
Hibernate: 
    update
        id_gen 
    set
        next_val=?  
    where
        next_val=? 
        and sequence_name=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        tbl.next_val 
    from
        id_gen tbl 
    where
        tbl.sequence_name=? for update
Hibernate: 
    update
        id_gen 
    set
        next_val=?  
    where
        next_val=? 
        and sequence_name=?
```

In my entity class the `allocationSize` is set to 100, but as you can see in the logs hibernate executes a sql query to get the next id every time.

Now I don't understand what is going on exactly. Am I doing something wrong? do I need more config? or maybe this log does not really get executed in the database. could someone please clarify this?

By the way, I'm using h2 database.

**Edit**

persistence.xml:

```
<properties>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:h2:~/library;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value = "true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        </properties>
```

DDL Logs:

```
Hibernate: 
    
    drop table if exists Book cascade 
Hibernate: 
    
    drop table if exists id_gen cascade 
Hibernate: 
    
    create table Book (
       id bigint not null,
        title varchar(255),
        primary key (id)
    )

Hibernate: 
    
    create table id_gen (
       sequence_name varchar(255) not null,
        next_val bigint,
        primary key (sequence_name)
    )
Hibernate: 
    
    insert into id_gen(sequence_name, next_val) values ('Book',0)
```

H2 tables:

[image: book table]
[image: id_gen table]

Comment: How do you generate the target table in this code?  Could you dump the DDL of table: Book in h2 database. 
I assume the result also depends on the target table, especially the sequence definition.